# ctrl + click disabled when using callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have an image, which is also a link, of a product in my e-commerce webpage, I want to track using google analytics enhanced ecommerce tool whenever somebody clicks on the image. To obtain more accurate data in my google analytics reports, I stop the link from navigating to the next page, until the event is done sending data.

This is the html of the link:

```
<a href="/product_path" onclick="onProductClick();return !ga.loaded;">
    <img src="/some_product.jpg" />
</a>
```

This is the javascript used:

```
<script>
    function onProductClick() {  

        ...

        ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Featured' {
            'hitCallback': function() {
                document.location = '/product_path'
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

However, this causes that when I press ctrl + click on the image it doesn't open in a new tab as usual, it opens in the same one I am right now. And this is a functionality I would like it to keep working.

Anyone has any idea on how to restore that functionality?

Comment: Why redirect in that situation? There is no need. Just let the tab open and log the click.

Comment: Something like `onclick="onProductClick();return !ga.loaded && !KeyboardJS.activeKeys().include('ctrl')"` should do the job :) [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/).

Comment: I think you mean: `onclick="onProductClick();return !ga.loaded || !KeyboardJS.activeKeys().include('ctrl')"`, right? Tried this and works but I have the problem now that the product page open in both tabs, and should open just in the new tab. Also, should this work with middle click?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
var my_event;
document.querySelector("#my_link").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    my_event= event;
    setTimeout(function(){//simulate your call to ga
        var window_target= my_event.ctrlKey ? "_newtab": "_self";
        window.open(my_event.target.href, window_target );
    },100);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

but it is not reliable, it does not, for example handles middle-click.

I would let the normal behaviour, the ga script make its request then the new page is opened like the user want. Actually, I do not see any problem.

```
document.querySelector("#my_link").addEventListener("click", function(){
 //ga call here
});
```